# How to tell eslint to allow staged ECMA-Script dynamic imports

Tags: javascript, eslint, ecmascript-harmony

I want to use the now "Stage-3" proposal `import()`. If I lint my code with ESLint it's complaining about:

```
Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level
```

Which is correct for the static form of `import` but not for the new, dynamic one. I don't find the right option to make ESLint allow that. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: ESLint natively supports stage 4 and above features. Anything below it, you have to use `babel-eslint` parser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course is Gyandeep right. It's no question of rules but of the parser (That's what parsing error means after all…). So I use now `babel-eslint` with the following `.eslintrc` (excerpt):

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "allowImportExportEverywhere": true
  }
}
```

Also, I made sure I installed and used [`babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/).

Comment: I do the above and still get error, described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145543/babel-eslint-does-not-allow-dynamic-import