# babel-eslint does not allow dynamic import

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, eslint

I use webpack 2 and I want to make dynamic import. Linter gives the following error on dynamic import (that is `import(...)` ):

> [js] Declaration or statement expected. (JSX attribute) import: true.

I have following `.eslintrc` (excerpt):

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "allowImportExportEverywhere": true
  }
}
```

Following is installed:

```
"eslint": "^3.16.1",
"babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
"babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack": "^1.0.1",
"babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
```

babelrc configuration:

```
{
    "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react"
    ],
    "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import", "dynamic-import-webpack"]
}
```

**Update:** Example where error occurs (react app). (Here the error is just `[js] Declaration or statement expected`):

```
const App = () => {

    import('./routes/Main/Main').then((Main) => {});
    return(<div />);
};
```

Comment: `allowImportExportEverywhere` has nothing to do with `import()`. The problem has probably nothing to do with your Babel configuration. Please post the code the linter complains about.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42394593/how-to-tell-eslint-to-allow-staged-ecma-script-dynamic-imports According to this, it is necessary.

Comment: `allowImportExportEverywhere` is a configuration for `import` and `export` *statements* not for `import` function calls. The error is strange though.

Comment: It is not because you have both `syntax-dynamic-import` and `dynamic-import-webpack` added to your config? shouldn't one of them be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why this happens.

It seems VSCode has internal javascript linter that is enabled even if eslint plugin is linting. Disabling this internal linter solves the
issue. So to solve, in project (`.vscode/settings.json`), user or global
VSCode settings set the following:

```
{
     ...other settings...,
    "javascript.validate.enable": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to the .eslintrc.js file solved it for me:

```
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        paths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
      },
    },
  },
```